# Querying Different Models with Ordering and Pagination

Tags: sql, django, database, django-rest-framework

I have a project where I store transactional records across about three models. These models have relatively different columns. I need to retrieve these records across these models for a `transactions` endpoint. The transactions need to be ordered in descending order by date across the models and also paginated.

The current implementation I have retrieves the records from the database using different querysets, then a sorted and chain method to order them by date before passing it to the paginator. This method happens to be expensive because the queryset has to be evaluated before pagination.

```py
model1_qs = Model1.objects.filter(...)
model2_qs = Model2.objects.filter(...)
model3_qs = Model3.objects.filter(...)


chained_list = sorted(chain(model1_qs, model2_qs, model3_qs), key=lambda: x: x.created, reverse=True)

# I pass this chained list to the paginator.
```

One other implementation I've tried is to combine the queryset using union, but I got this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns` and when I tried to use annotate to make the columns equal on both sides, I got a couple of errors like this:
`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`

I have decided against going this route because it was beginning to look hacky.

Is there any other way I can achieve this in a more efficient way without first pulling out all the records from the DB?